# How to setup multisite drupal7 using the ubuntu packages in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, drupal

I want to install Drupal 7 in such a way that I can have multiple websites using the same code base on one machine.
I the past I have done that by manually downloading Drupal 7. However this time I would like to do it with the ubuntu packages.
However, I am unable to find any documentation on how to do it. The closest I found is: https://drupal.org/node/138889

However, that tutorial does not seem to be applicable anymore, since the location of a couple of files has changed.
Furthermore, the more I can do this without user interaction, the better. (For example I prefer to install the packages myself compared to tasksel, because I can automate that with fabric/cuisine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and digging into how Drupals multi site functionality works I have solved my own problem. I will document it here for anyone else:

First install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install drupal7 mysql-server php5-json
```

Then some apache configuration:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2enmod deflate
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Then some php configuration change values in (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini):

```
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
```

Then configure mysql:

```
mysql -u root -e 'CREATE USER '<drupalAdminUser>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The main configuration is now done, the following steps should be repeated for each site you want to add to your multisite setup.

Create the host file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.com.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/drupal7/
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the configuration:

```
sudo ln -s  /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourdomain.com.conf
```

Copy the drupal default site bits:

```
sudo cp -a /etc/drupal/7/sites/default /etc/drupal/7/sites/yourdomain.com
```

Create the mysql db for the new site:

```
mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE yourdomain_com';
mysql -u root -e 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON yourdomain_com.* TO '<drupalAdminUser>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';'
```

Update the db information in (/etc/drupal/7/sites/yourdomain.com/dbconfig.php)

Now go to yourdomain.com/install.php